# Getting the size of some rows in a MySQL-Table

Tags: mysql, size

I need to get the physical size of some rows in a MySQL-Table.

There are some solutions how to read out the size of a whole table over the information scheme, e.g. [this article](http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/getting-mysql-table-size-with-php/).

Is there a way to get the size of a subset of a table? Of course I could manually read out every field in every tuple and get the bytes of the stored word. But I hope there is a better/faster solution.

Comment: What would constitute the "size" of a row?  Just the size of the contents?  Or would you include some portion of the indices?  What about other data?

Comment: I'm just interested in the size of the content stored in the rows.

@zerkms: some (but not all, I also want include varchars and so on) columns are of type blob, and I need to check if a user has reached a specified limit of storage.